# Android wear app won't install with NDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, wear-os

We're trying to publish our Android wearable app via mobile apk, so the wearable app gets synced automatically to the watch. This works fine if the app does not contain the NDK part.

However if we include the NDK/jni to our sources, the app will not install via the mobile.apk. The app installs via building in android studio and adb (adb -e install wearable.apk).

This is our build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.high_mobility.digitalkey"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            moduleName = "hmbtcore"
            ldLibs "log"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' // This is not necessary unless you have precompiled libraries in your project.
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
}
```

[Here is the adb from the mobile side when installing com.high_mobility.digitalkey](https://slack-files.com/T054XT13D-F19E49L3B-e9432204f6)

What might be the issue here that we cannot publish our app via the mobile apk?

Comment: Hi, any luck with this?

Comment: The workaround(and actually how we needed the NDK) was to bundle the NDK part in a separate module.